# How to recover when after updating Ndivia driver, the graphic driver is disabled

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I've done the classic `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

I've been asked to update to latest Nvidia drivers. After a lot of "update" lines, I reboot. Now, when I boot I get this: two black screens, only the top "on" with a mouse I can't even move. My keyboard works, but (I guess!) the video driver is so broken that when I try to get a console via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>, nothing happens. If I press 7 times <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> it works and reboot. Here are my two screens, blank and of no use:

[image: blank screens]

When I boot, I try to edit the boot option by typing `e` and I didn't find on the Web the option to add / remove to boot as command line and force installation of the old driver.

- Should I comment "`load_video`"? If so, how to comment?
- Should I comment "`gfx_mode $linux_gfx_mode`"? If so, how to comment?
- Should I add / remove an option after "`linux /boot/vmlinuz-...blabla quiet splash`"?

Comment: I'm not sure but I have posted a question recently which I am beginning to think is also nvidia-related. Could you remove the "quiet" from your boot options as this will give us more info?

Comment: It's not really nvidia-related, it's about "when your video driver doesn't work, what are the possibilities" and until this night - 4am, I didnt find a working solution. I'll post my working solution here when I have some time.